# c daemon() for unix doesnt work with sleep()

Tags: c, sleep, daemon

I have very simple code that should run on background and at 1 am shut down the computer:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    time_t t;struct tm * now;
    daemon(0,0);
    while(1){
        t = time(0);
        now = localtime( & t );
        if(now->tm_hour==1){
           system("shutdown -P");
           break;
        }
        sleep(10);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code works without sleep(10) but uses whole free memory so I need sleep function there to stop loop and recheck time each ten seconds, but with sleep function program stops immediately after I run it.

Comment: How do you know it stops ? You call daemon() so it'll put itself in the background, and not consume any noticeable resources/CPU.

Comment: Check the return value of daemon()

Comment: As a side note, did you know that `shutdown` already has the feature you are implementing? (`shutdown -P 01:00`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are writing C code, don't use C++ headers (`ctime`, `cstdlib`).  Replace those `#include`s with `#include <stdlib.h>` and `#include <time.h>`.  If the behavior of this code is really as you describe (which I would find surprising), then this is probably the source of the error.

Comment: Sure this had to cause the problem because now it runs, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it immediately exits. Thats the whole point of using `daemon`. Check with `ps` and you will see that your proram is still running as a seperate process now.

Check the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html) for a desription how `daemon` works.